# How to get a tree structured table data by linq?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, tree

I have a table which has a tree structure in itself.

```
Id ParentId Name
----------------
1    null   x
2    null   y
3    null   z
4    null   t
5     1     xx
6     1     xy
7     1     xz
8     2     yx
9     2     yy
10    9     yyx
11    10    yyxx
12    11    yyxxx
```

I want to retrieve the whole sub-tree under a root node. When my root node is "x" I want to get the set of nodes {1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12}. How can I do that by linq?

Answer (score 1):

If you're able the change the table structure to add extra fields, then one approach I have used in the past is to have a "Path" field, which holds a comma separated list of IDs.

```
ID    ParentID    Name      Path
--    --------    ----      ----
1     null        x         1
2     null        y         2
3     null        z         3
4     null        t         4
5     1           xx        1,5
6     1           xy        1,6
7     1           xz        1,7
8     2           yx        2,8
9     2           yy        2,9
10    9           yyx       2,9,10
11    10          yyxx      2,9,10,11
12    11          yyxxx     2,9,10,11,12
```

Then you can query based on the Path field using LIKE (or StartsWith in Linq)

In your question you say you want to get { 1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12 }, but those IDs are part of two different sub-trees, if I've read it right.

To get "x" and all it's children ...

```
where Path = "1" || Path.StartsWith("1,")
```

To just get x's children ...

```
where Path.StartsWith("1,")
```

Comment: Nice solution, someones -as me- think that "simple" is the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows to recursively select descendants as plain collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="DescendBy"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    public static IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> DescendBy)
    {
        foreach (T value in source)
        {
            yield return value;

            foreach (var child in DescendBy(value).Descendants(DescendBy))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:
node.children.Descendants(node=>node.children);

Answer (score 0):

You need to Perform Inner Join In Linq with the Table Itself as follows :

```
from root in TableName 
join subnodes in TableName on root.Id equals subnodes.ParentId
select new { Name }
```

This will retrieve all those records which parent id matches with Id with same table renamed as subnodes

Thanks